# Form field modified in directive linking function no longer validated correctly?

Tags: angularjs

I have an `input` element on which I have `ng-required ng-pattern="/[0-9]{5}/"`.

It also has a directive which adds an error message, and which has the following linking function and other related properties:

```
   return {
        scope: {},
        require: ['^^form', 'ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            // Places error message element after input element.
            var el = angular.element('<span>')
                .append(element.clone().removeAttr('mp-validated-field')) // else recurses
                .append('<span ng-show="showError" class="errorMsg">{{ error }}</span>');
            el = el[0].innerHTML;

            var tmp = $compile(el)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(tmp);
            element = tmp;
            ctrls[0].$addControl(ctrls[1]);
        },
        controller: // etc
```

What should be happening here is that a `span` operating as an error message is placed after the `input` element automatically by the directive. As written, this happens, however I have to use `$addControl` to get the formController to re-register the input after that.

What happens when I run this *with a blank input* (so it should fail `required`) is that the formController's `$error` hash for this field contains `{pattern: false}`, which is to say it thinks there's only a pattern validation, no required validation, and that the pattern validation is passing despite that it's the regex `/[0-9]{5}/` (zipcode).

What am I missing here?

**Edit:** I moved the ng-required and ng-pattern directives to be before my custom directive and now it recognizes both of them, however it just fails on ng-required arbitrarily every time, regardless of whether it is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/qoanok28/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('myError', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: ['ngModel'],
      scope: {
        ngModel: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var span = angular.element('<div ng-show="showError" class="error">{{error}}</div>');
        elem.after(span);
        $compile(span)(scope);
        scope.error = 'Zip code must be not 0000';
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(val) {
          if (val == '00000')
            scope.showError = true;
          else
            scope.showError = false;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <input type="text" ng-model="zip" name="zip" my-error ng-pattern="/[0-9]{5}/" required>
      <div ng-show='testForm.zip.$error.required' class='error'>Is required</div>
      <div ng-show='testForm.zip.$error.pattern' class='error'>Invalid pattern</div>
      <br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="zip2" name="zip2" ng-pattern="/[0-9]{5}/" required my-error>
      <div ng-show='testForm.zip2.$error.required' class='error'>Is required</div>
      <div ng-show='testForm.zip2.$error.pattern' class='error'>Invalid pattern</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

But for complex custom checks i recommend [use-form-error](http://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/wL9c2feo/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  });
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="myForm" use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==9">
      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error" style="color:maroon">
        <div ng-message="formInvalid">You form is not valid</div>
      </div>
      <label>Your number should be even, not divisible by three and should not be 6,7,9:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="digit" name="myDigit" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" required use-form-error="isEven" use-error-expression="digit%2==0" />
      <span use-form-error="isDividedThree" use-error-expression="digit%3==0" use-error-input="myForm.myDigit"></span>
      <span use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==7" use-error-input="myForm.myDigit"></span>
      <span use-form-error="formInvalid" use-error-expression="digit==6"></span>
      <pre>myForm.myDigit.$error = {{ myForm.myDigit.$error | json }}</pre>

      <div ng-messages="myForm.myDigit.$error" ng-messages-multiple="true" style="color:maroon">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a digit</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your digit is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your digit is too long</div>
        <div ng-message="isEven">Your digit is even</div>
        <div ng-message="isDividedThree">Your digit is divided by three</div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```